# How to arrange buttons created in runtime in a GRID?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Is there any proper or simple way to arrange the button in a GRID?? I've buttons created in runtime.

Here is the format:

```
Button1      Button2     Button3

Button4      Button5     Button6

Button7      Button8     Button9
```

I am using C#.net with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a TableLayoutPanel before you create the Buttons and add the Buttons to the TableLayoutPanel, then add the TableLayoutPanel to the parent-control on which you wanted to show the Buttons.

There should even be a possibility to add the buttons to a specific cell of the TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)... I'm sure there are other alternatives, but that's worked pretty well for me in the past. In particular, it gives you reasonable control over how the contents are sized - and resized. You need to think about how the space should be distributed between the buttons, particularly if they won't all be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

in grid already you can make a format by columns and rows so there is no need for arrangement only you need to specify the column type as button